# django queryset to get average of a group

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-filter

This is kind of tricky!

I have a db that keeps track of each users download usages in KB, of every hour(24 entry per day); 
looks like this..

### user   timestamp  usage

user1  2013-0501 14:00:00   229

user2  2013-0501 14:00:00   103

user1  2013-0501 13:00:00   220

user2  2013-0501 13:00:00   103

now I need the average usage of each user for every day

any way to create a queryset for that?

Im thinking to do this.. (but cant execute)

for each user (bundle) or get the entries of same day and average them..
but this is all I got!

```
myValue = Members.objects.order_by('-time')
myValue = myValue.filter(user='user1')
myValue = myValue.annotate(dcount=Count('timestamp'))
```

how can I get Count or better list of "myValue.annotate(dcount=Count('timestamp__day'))"
and get average of that bundle..

```
myAvg = myValue.aggregate(Avg('usage'))
```

Thanks for any help, let me know if this is confusing!

Answer (score 0):

I would say this is a typical case of a query that doesn't map cleanly to your models. 
The results are of the type (user,date,avg_usage), and for a fixed user of the type (date,avg_usage). So it doesn't map well to a single user object, nor to a single user_usage entry. This is why the ORM built in aggregates won't get you far.(AFAIK)

Since this is a very simple SQL query, I'd go the raw SQL route (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly):

Assuming date(timestamp) is the SQL operation to convert your timestamp to a date (depends on the DB) and user_usage is the table, these are the queries:

To get this for one user:

```
select date(timestamp) as date, avg(usage) 
    from user_usage where user_id = %s  
    group by date(timestamp)
```

and to get this for all users at once:

```
select user_id, date(timestamp) as date, avg(usage) 
    from user_usage
    group by user_id,date(timestamp)
```